# Reverse proxy configuration for Karma during Angular testing

Tags: angular, karma-runner

My application makes calls to a backend web service. During development I configure reverse proxy for the Angular CLI server and everything works fine.

```
ng serve --proxy-config proxy.config.json
```

I need to do the same for Karma during unit testing. I add this to `karma.conf.js`.

```
proxies: {
  "/books":"http://localhost:3000/",
  "/books/*":"http://localhost:3000/",
}
```

None of this works. My calls always get 404. If, however, I configure a full URL, it works.

```
proxies: {
  "/books/167":"http://localhost:3000/books/167"
}
```

How can I properly configure reverse proxy using wildcard?

Comment: Have you tried like `proxies: {
  "/books": { target: "http://localhost:3000/"}
}`. If that does help, try `proxies: {
  "/books/*": { target: "http://localhost:3000/"}
}`

Comment: @olegario, does your call go from `/books/167` to `http://localhost:3000/167` or `http://localhost:3000/books/167`? Because the later one needs additional config

Comment: @olegario, any update/feedback on the same?

Comment: does `proxies: { "/books":"http://localhost:3000/books" }` work?

Comment: had a similar problem, using something like proxies: { "/books/","http://localhost:3000/books/" } worked for me

Answer (score 4):

You should not use backend in the unit test. As the name shows it is about testing in units. The dependencies of the unit you test (e.g. service or component) should be mocked. This way real http service won't be called, only a mock (e.g. Observable) with the same functionality, so only the unit will be tested and the test won't fail because of the dependency.

The proxy is only needed in the e2e test as it tests the application as a whole. The `e2e` tests inherit the `--proxy-config` option from the `serve` script.

Examples:

- [MockBackend for test](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/unit-testing/http-and-jsonp/)
- [Testing guide](https://angular.io/guide/testing)

Comment: My question was not about if I should use backend in unit test or not. I am fully aware that I should attempt to mock services during unit testing. But in real life this is not always possible to mock every call in all situations. That is why I asked a specific question.

Comment: Everything can be mocked, however it needs sometimes more time than creating the original service. This way move things that you can to the unit tests and create e2e tests for that parts you cannot mock.

Comment: @RajV androbin is right : you should always mock your dependencies. Even Angular pushes you to do so : for HTTP calls, you should use `HttpClientTestingModule` instead of the actual module. Your unit tests are supposed to test function by function, not make the work of the e2e tests.

Comment: trichetriche, nobody is saying he is wrong. I agree with him completely. But that is not the purpose of this specific question.

Comment: @RajV, did you get a chance to try my first comment?

Comment: Tarun, sorry I have been very busy. I apologize. I will do my best to test this next week.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

proxies: { "/books":"http://localhost:3000/books" }

Please let me know whether it works